# Dropdown Menu troubles in IE9/Windows 7

Tags: javascript, asp.net, cascadingdropdown

I have page developed using the Asp.Net and Javascript 
I have a drop down and when I am clicking on the drop down its getting expanded and getting freezed and unable to select item from the drop down by mouse adding to it I am able to select the item from that DropDown by means of the key board and it is happenning only few time and in few machines . Unable to find out if that could be a javascript issue / I.E version Issue / CSS issue . 
Please let me know if any more info is required

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Try it in other browser, like Chrome. If it does work it'll probably be a css issue in IE. Create a jsfiddle with code where you can reproduce the issue

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I have a constrain that my applciation will be used in IE only

Comment: Still, it becomes practically impossible to help you if you don't post some code so someone can check it and suggest a fix.